# Reseting the TotalCount (totcount) each section

Tags: lists, counters, programming, totcount

I am trying to set-up a system where I can total a counter for each section and print this, then reset each section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{myCounter}[section]
\regtotcounter{myCounter}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
    \label{sec:sec1}

    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\

\section{sec2}
    \label{sec:sec2}

    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\total{myCounter}\\

\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
1 sec1
1/6
2/6
3/6
4/6

2 sec2
1/6
2/6
3/6
4/6
5/6
6/6
```

Desired result:

```
1 sec1
1/4
2/4
3/4
4/4

2 sec2
1/6
2/6
3/6
4/6
5/6
6/6
```

I have attempted to do `\regtotcounter{myCounter}` but no luck.

Comment: +1 for a very good MWE. It would appear that the `totcount` package assumes that the counter variables of interest are *global* rather than section-specific. Put differently, the package doesn't appear to be set up to deal with counters (e.g., `myCounter`) that get reset each time some other counter (e.g., `section`) is stepped. Asking to modify the `totcount` package to handle subordinated counters would amount to a feature request, and feature requests are off-topic on this site. Have you contacted the maintainer of the `totcount` package directly?

Comment: Thanks, but not wishing for a feature request. Solution below is good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it with `totcount`. Possibly with `xassoccnt`, but it has become unmaintained.

Here's a standalone solution, where at each section change something is written out in the `.aux` file (and also `\AtEndDocument`): for each registered counter, its final value is associated to the current section number.

Therefore we're able to know the total for each section at the next run.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\savesectioncounters}
\AtEndDocument{\savesectioncounters}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g__panda_counters_clist
\prop_new:N \g__panda_counters_prop

\AtBeginDocument{\prop_show:N \g__panda_counters_prop}

\NewDocumentCommand{\declaresectioncounter}{m}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g__panda_counters_clist { #1 }
 }


\NewDocumentCommand{\savesectioncounters}{}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g__panda_counters_clist
   {
    \iow_shipout:cx { @mainaux } { \sectioncountertotal{##1}{\use:c{the##1}}{\arabic{section}} }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\sectioncountertotal}{mmm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g__panda_counters_prop { #1@#3 } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getsectiontotal}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Ne \g__panda_counters_prop { #1@\arabic{section} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{myCounter}[section]
\declaresectioncounter{myCounter}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
    \label{sec:sec1}

    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}

\section{sec2}
    \label{sec:sec2}

    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}\\
    \stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter/\getsectiontotal{myCounter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - great solution